# Entity Framework 7 / Core code-first mapping to stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am new to Entity Framework 7 code-first and came across a mapping issue with stored procedure.

Below are two classes where `cityid` is the relational property:

```
public class CityList
{
        [Key]
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string CityDescription { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PointOfInterestList> PointOfInterestList { get; set; } = new List<PointOfInterestList>();
}

public class PointOfInterestList
{
        [Key]
        public int PointsofInterestId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string PointsofInterestName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string PointsofInterestDescription { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CityId")]
        public CityList CityList { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
}
```

Using `DbContext` to populate the `CityList` object from a stored procedure `GetCity`:

```
var returnlist = _context.CitiesList.FromSql("GetCity @p0", CityId).ToList();
```

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetCity]
    (@CityId INT = 0)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @CityId = 0
        SET @CityId = NULL

    SELECT 
        c.Id CityId, C.Description CityDescription, C.Name CityName--,c.Country
        ,p.Id PointsofInterestId, p.Name PointsofInterestName, p.Description PointsofInterestDescription
    FROM 
        dbo.Cities c 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.PointOfInterest p ON p.CityId = c.Id
    WHERE 
        c.Id = ISNULL(@CityId, c.Id)
END
```

The stored procedure gets executed and populates the `CityList` collection, but the `PointOfInterestList` collection within each `CityList` object does not get mapped with the stored procedure result.

Let me know if I have missed any step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you map via a stored procedure, it isn't smart enough to know about any Includes are doing (since you can't do .Include(...)).  It only knows the direct fields on the entity you are directly mapping to.  Thus, the only way you'd be able to fix this is to create your own DTO that has both the header and lines in it and then have a custom map to push that data into the appropriate entities, along with having to deal with the duplicate header data yourself. (i.e. If you have 2 lines, you'd need 1 header and then add both lines to that header. Uniqueness based on PK would work.)

Edit - Example:

```
public class MyCustomRowDto
{
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public string CityDescription { get; set; }

        public int PointsofInterestId { get; set; }
        public string PointsofInterestName { get; set; }
        public string PointsofInterestDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you call the stored procedure:

```
var list = context.Database.SqlQuery<MyCustomRowDto>("...").ToList();
```

Then you'll need some sort of mapping layer with a dictionary for the primary key. Something like this:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, CityList>();

foreach (var item in list) {
   CityList entity;
   if (!data.TryGet(item.CityId, out entity)) {
      entity = new CityList() { CityId = item.CityId, CityName = item.CityName ..., PointOfInterestList = new List<PointOfInterestList>() };
      data.Add(item.CityId, entity);
   }
   entity.PointOfInterest.Add(new PointOfInterestList() { PointOfInterestId = item.PointofInterestId, ..., CityId = item.CityId, CityList = entity
}

return data.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Daniel, but can you please be more info on "headers and lines" as per your comments.

Comment: See added example above.

Comment: Daniel, the code helped and worked as expected result. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! :-)